# Facebook app using github-hosted page

Tags: facebook, nginx, github-pages

I need to render a little and static website inside a `Facebook app`, in order to set a new `Tab for a Facebook page` just like [Ferrari](https://www.facebook.com/Ferrari/app_237133999688993) does.

To achieve this I have to create a website, host it and then create a Facebook app in order to render the website inside it.

The first problem was that I don't have a webhost with SSL in order to set up Secure URLs in my facebook app settings, so I decided to use github pages. My site was super easy and static so I though that github pages will do the job for me.

But when I configure my Facebook app to render my github-hosted website, see the error and my actual app settings:

> **[Image album for error and settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zljKA.jpg)**.

I've read about nginx 405 error, and it seems to be mostly because of webserver configuration, and the way that facebook "calls" the iframes/websites via POST.

So my question is, how can I get a solution for this by myself?

Comment: Just found this http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2011/05/20/405-not-allowed-error-serving-facebook-apps-with-nginx/ but still, nothing I can do :(

Comment: For one thing, GitHub Pages doesn't support https, so I'm not sure you're going to get the SSL benefit you are looking for from it. Also, you can find the help docs here: https://help.github.com/categories/20/articles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of September 10, 2014 it's not possible to achieve.

Github pages' webserver doesn't allow POST calls to static content, as facebook does.